# Changing highcharts crosshairs position with clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a crosshairs on my chart and I want to change its position with a button click. After clicking on the chart my crosshairs would be sticky and its position would be changed with clicking "next" and "previous" buttons. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add a code sample of what you already have? I believe this would make it easier for others to help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of crosshairs, use plotLines - on click event add them, and on  button click remove old plotLine and add new one.

See docs:

- addPlotLine: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine
- removePlotLine: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine
- plotLine options: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines
- click events: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click

Comment: Using plotLines is my second solution. If I can't find a solution with crosshairs then I will use plotLines. Thank you.